# How to stop rewriting of index Lucene.net c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, lucene, lucene.net

I was been doing indexing using lucene.net in WPF C# and suddenly got that new every new doc was added instead of previous and thus the any moment number of docs in index was 1

I don't know how can this happen because I have tested the same adding methods in C# Console but in forms it just something strange happen

Can't you suggest how to solve the problem?

This is the code of where the method to create index is called

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LuceneSearch.LuceneEngine le = new LuceneSearch.LuceneEngine();
           var engine = new FileEngine();

            if (txtboxName.Text != "" && cmbboxDis.SelectedIndex != -1 && btnFile.Content.ToString() != "Choose a file")
            {//adds some stuff to DB and returns an object to index
               var IndexMe= engine.AddFile(txtboxName.Text, cmbboxDis.SelectedIndex, txtboxAuth.Text, txtboxTags.Text, txtboxComment.Text);
                le.BuildIndex(IndexMe);//index this file

                this.Close();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Not all fields are filled", "Oops!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You haven't chosen a file! " +ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

That's the way how it looks in class of lucene methods

```
namespace StudentWorksSearch.LuceneSearch
{
public  class LuceneEngine
{//get directory
      private const string _luceneDir = "../../../Data/lucene_index1";
    private   FSDirectory _directoryTemp;
    private    FSDirectory _directory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_directoryTemp == null) _directoryTemp = FSDirectory.Open(new
        DirectoryInfo(_luceneDir));
            if (IndexWriter.IsLocked(_directoryTemp)) IndexWriter.Unlock(_directoryTemp);
            var lockFilePath = Path.Combine(_luceneDir, "write.lock");
            if (File.Exists(lockFilePath)) File.Delete(lockFilePath);
            return _directoryTemp;
        }
    }


    //this method creates document from an ObjectToIndex
    public   void BuildIndex(FileToIndex file)
    {
        using (var analyzer = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Ru.RussianAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30))
        {
            using (IndexWriter idxw = new IndexWriter(_directory, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
            {
                //check if document exists, if true deletes existing                    
                var searchQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("Id", file.Id.ToString()));
                idxw.DeleteDocuments(searchQuery);
                //creation
                Document doc = new Document();
                doc.Add(new Field("Id", file.Id.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));//аналайзер разбивает строки на слова
                doc.Add(new Field("Title", file.Title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                doc.Add(new Field("Description", file.Description, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                doc.Add(new Field("Authors", file.Authors, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                doc.Add(new Field("Text", file.Text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                doc.Add(new Field("Hashtags", file.Hashtags, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                //write the document to the index
                idxw.AddDocument(doc);

                //optimize and close the writer
                idxw.Commit();

                idxw.Optimize();                  
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument to the IndexWriter constructor specifies whether it should create a new index.  If it is set to `true`, it will overwrite any existing index and create a new one.  You should set it to `false` to open an existing index:

```
IndexWriter idxw = new IndexWriter(_directory, analyzer, false, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED
```